# Laravel Access css and js file from resources css and js directory

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-8

This is my directory structure.

```
-resources
  -css
    -mycss.css
  -js
    -myjs.js
  -myimagesfolder
  -views
    -admin
      -home.blade.php
```

how can i access **resources>css>mycss.css** , **resources>js>myjs.js** and **resources>mymagesfolder>images**  in my **views>admin>home.blade.php**.

Comment: You need to store your publicly available files and folders under the ``public`` folder and then you can use the ``asset()`` helper method to generate. E.g. in your blade file use, ``<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }} />``

Comment: @OMiShah and css and Js?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Put your css and js file inside public folder like this:

```
-public
  -css
    -mycss.css
  -js
    -myjs.js
```

Now you can access your files like this.Putthis below line of code inside head tag

For css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mycss.css')}}">
```

For Js

```
<script src="{{asset('js/myjs.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

According to Laravel official documents [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#introduction), files under /resources/css, /resources/js **need be compiled** before use.

Comment: compiled as in... doing what exactly? npm install / npm run dev ?

Answer (score 6):

You can compile files in `resources/css` `resources/js` with Laravel mix.

For `myjs.js`, add to `webpack.mix.js` file the line: `mix.js('resources/js/myjs.js', 'public/js');`
For `mjcss.css`, add to `webpack.mix.js` file the line: `mix.postCss('resources/mycss.css', 'public/css');`

Both `myjs.js` and `mycss.css` will be compiled to public/js and public/css respectively when you run `npm run dev`

Remember to include the minified js and css files in your `app.blade.php`

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/myjs.js') }}" defer></script>

  <link href="{{ asset('css/mycss.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please move all your **public** files to the `public` folder:

```
-public
  -css
    -mycss.css
  -js
    -myjs.js
-resources
  -myimagesfolder
  -views
    -admin
      -home.blade.php
```

then import them as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/mycss.css')}}"> ## CSS
<script src="{{asset('js/myjs.js')}}"></script> ## JS
```

Best of luck!